# How to create function to convert dictionary to a matrix without numpy or any similar package

Tags: python, function, dictionary, matrix, converters

You are given a dictionary which is mapping of number and feature. Create a function to convert dictionary to a matrix without numpy or any similar package. Simply use basic python operations.
Input Dictionary:

```
{
11:['a','b','c']
22:['c','d','e'] }
```

output must be like this:

```
[ ['tag','a','b','c','d','e']
  [11,1,1,1,0,0] 
  [22,0,0,1,1,1] 
]
```

I tried but cant so help

Comment: Are the features always in sorted order?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Sounds like a school quiz. What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, features always in sorted order

Comment: There is no matrix type in "vanilla" python.  Do you mean [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)?

Comment: Bro in output its a matrix not list . its looking like list in list but consider it matrix

Answer (score 0):

next time please don't forget to add what everyone has asked you to do in comments :)

```
d = {
    11:['a','b','c'],
    22:['c','d','e']
    }

all_val =  ['tag']
# using list comprehension
  # for v in d.values() <-- outer loop
    # for _ in v <-- inner loop
# set because idk whether each key have unique set of values 

for char in sorted(set([ _ for v in d.values() for _ in v] )):
    all_val.append(char)

output_2d = []
output_2d.append(all_val)

for k,v in d.items():
    output_2d.append([k])
    for tag in all_val[1:]:
        if tag in v:
            output_2d[-1].append(1)
        else:
            output_2d[-1].append(0)


print(output_2d)
```

[['tag', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], [11, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [22, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]